# Salesforce Scheduled Path Flow not allowing to activate

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow, scheduled-action

I created a record-triggered flow that fires when the record is created/updated and created a scheduled path with time source as when the record is created/updated showing an error when trying to save flow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Even tried to update the flow to when record is updated but still issue exists.